# How do I tag a specific revision in Mercurial when promoting a build in Jenkins?

Tags: mercurial, jenkins

I have a Jenkins CI server with the Promoted Builds plug-in and the Mercurial plug-in.  What I would like to do when a build gets promoted is tag the revision in Mercurial that corresponds to that build.

The Mercurial plug-in exposes an environment variable called MERCURIAL_REVISION_NUMBER, and this is populated when the build runs, but not when the promotion runs.  So when I try do the following in an "Execute a Windows batch command" step in my promotion:

`hg tag --rev %MERCURIAL_REVISION_NUMBER% "Promoted-%PROMOTED_NUMBER%-%PROMOTED_ID%"`

it fails because %MERCURIAL_REVISION_NUMBER% evaluates to an empty string, so there is no value supplied to the --rev argument.

I do notice that the Mercurial revision is saved in the build.xml file for each build.  I'm wondering if there is an easy way to get to it in my promotion step.

Comment: What kind of "fails"?  Output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it with a Powershell script.  This is my first PS script, so I'm certainly open to any suggested improvements.

```
# Read the appropriate Hg revision from build.xml and tag it
$filename = "..\builds\" + $env:PROMOTED_ID  + "\build.xml"
[xml]$build = Get-content $filename
$hg = $build.SelectSingleNode("/build/actions/hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialTagAction")
write-host "Tagging revision: " + $hg.rev
hg tag --force --rev $hg.rev "Promoted-$env:PROMOTED_NUMBER-$env:PROMOTED_ID"
hg push --force
```

Answer (score 2):

That build.xml must be something your Jenkins script is creating -- Mercurial doesn't.

Your Mercurial command looks fine.

One option is to just put the build info into a file as part of your jenkins script:

```
hg id > $WORKSPACE/built-version
```

and then include `built-version` as one of the build's artifacts.  Then your promotion script can do:

```
hg tag --rev $(< built-version) "Promoted-${PROMOTED_NUMBER}-${PROMOTED_ID}"
```

or whatever the windows equivalent of that is.

Comment: The Mercurial command itself is correct.  The issue is on the Jenkins side -- Jenkins is losing track of which revision I need to tag.  I'm looking for how to know the specific revision that corresponds to this build.